# How to resolve the issue of Displaying Hero Cards and Form Flow in Skype Channel?

Tags: botframework

I am working on bot framework technology, in one of project I implemented code for Hero cards and Thumbnail Cards.

After I added the code for above concept, next I was tested in Bot Framework Channel Emulator its working fine and displayed Hero cards successfully. But after I published my code into azure and added skype channel to my bot then now I started to chat with my bot to display hero card images but it's not displaying any hero card images it display like this below screenshot.
[image]

Similarly I implemented Form Flow Concept It's working in Bot Emulator fine but it’s not working in skype channel its show same issue like above figure.

Please tell how to resolve this Issue.
I think there may be a bug in Skype to display the Hero Card and Form Flow dialogs.

Pradeep

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is not a bug in Skype, but rather a missing feature. The normal Skype clients (desktop, web, mobile) have not been updated to include HeroCards yet, so they can't be displayed, except the iOS ones (see http://blogs.skype.com/2016/07/20/skype-6-20-for-ios-find-bots-improved-notifications-and-chat/)

As hinted on the botbuilder project, you can use `{listStyle: builder.ListStyle["inline"]}` as workaround to show your content as option list instead of a card. See: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/720.

Otherwise all you can do for now is either install developer builds that include the feature or wait for the updated versions (which should come out soon).

Comment: Thanks for reply, I was busting my head thinking this is some problem with my code.

Comment: Any update on this answer? as of now also the hero card is not displaying in skype.

Comment: This is already supported by Skype. Cards works well as you can see in the sample https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/cards-RichCards.

Answer (score 0):

It works. Skype is another channel. In most cases code developed using the bot framework will work on skype, some features need to be specific to skype. So in order to make your card work you will have to replace the botbuilder by skype. See example below that was taken from [Microsoft hero card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-send-rich-cards) and modify to work in skype
[skype hero card result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byx0U.png)

```js
Replace builder by skype
//var builder = require('botbuilder');

var skype = require('botbuilder');

var msg = new skype.Message(session);
    msg.attachmentLayout(skype.AttachmentLayout.carousel)
    msg.attachments([
        new skype.HeroCard(session)
            .title("Classic White T-Shirt")
            .subtitle("100% Soft and Luxurious Cotton")
            .text("Price is $25 and carried in sizes (S, M, L, and XL)")
            .images([skype.CardImage.create(session, 'https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/6422482?v=4&s=460')])
            .buttons([
                skype.CardAction.imBack(session, "buy classic white t-shirt", "Buy")
            ]),
        new skype.HeroCard(session)
            .title("Classic Gray T-Shirt")
            .subtitle("100% Soft and Luxurious Cotton")
            .text("Price is $25 and carried in sizes (S, M, L, and XL)")
            .images([skype.CardImage.create(session, 'https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/6422482?v=4&s=460')])
            .buttons([
                skype.CardAction.imBack(session, "buy classic gray t-shirt", "Buy")
            ])
    ]);
    session.send(msg);
```